# Why am I unable to connect to yarn?

Tags: hadoop, hadoop-yarn

I'm trying to connect to yarn by doing `yarn application -list`.  But I cannot because it says:

```
<date> <time> INFO client.RMProxy: Connecting to ResourceManager at /0.0.0.0:8032
<date> <time> INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connecting to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 0 time(s): retyr policy is RetryUpToMaximumCountWithFixedSleep(maxRetries=10, sleepTime= 1000 MILLISECONDS)
<date> <time> INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connecting to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 1 time(s): retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCount
<date> <time> INFO ipc.Client: Retrying connecting to server: 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0:8032. Already tried 2 time(s): retry policy is RetryUpToMaximumCount
```

I have a file under `/etc/hadoop/conf.empty/yarn-site.xml`, which I assume is related to this in some way.   I have a file at `/etc/hadoop/conf.empty/` called `yarn-env.sh`.  I tried running this file, but it didn't change anything.

Am I doing something wrong?  Or maybe something is not correctly configured?  How do I start yarn?

Comment: How did you start the yarn deamon?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`yarn-site.xml` is for configuring YARN daemons `ResourceManager`, `NodeManager` and `ApplicationMaster`. The properties relating to these services go in here. And the environment settings for YARN can be modified with `yarn-env.sh`.

Start YARN services, (From the path of `yarn-site.xml` file posted, the installation does not appear to be done using tarballs. So the startup scripts might not be available)

On ResourceManager host

```
sudo service hadoop-yarn-resourcemanager start
```

And on each NodeManager host

```
sudo service hadoop-yarn-nodemanager start
```

**Note:** Make sure the preliminary configuration properties are set for both HDFS and YARN and the HDFS daemons `Namenode` and `Datanode` are started and running.

Additionally, Configure the mapreduce to use `yarn` in `mapred-site.xml`

```
<property>
 <name>mapreduce.framework.name</name>
 <value>yarn</value>
</property>
```

Comment: franklinsijo and @FelicePollano you are both suggesting different solutions.  ONe suggests running the bash scripts, and one suggests running the services.  Which one (or both?) is correct?

Comment: what is the difference between these?

Comment: @Sother, the correct one depends on the installation method followed. If the binary tarball has been downloaded and extracted, it contains the startup scripts which can be used to start the services. But if this installation mode is not followed and installers like `apt` or `yum` were used to install from repositories they do not contain the scripts instead you have to use the services to start and stop the daemons. The configuration files location suggest me that the latter method has been followed.

Comment: And your post hinting that you have not modified any of these xml files also shows that the configuring of services is not done. You have to add some basic configuration properties before you can use them. If it is a quick start VM, should not be the case as they are readymade with basic configurations

Answer (score 0):

You need to start the hadoop service, at least you need to start:

```
start-dfs.sh
start-yarn.sh
```

these shell script are located in the hadoop bin folder.
Depending on the installation maybe you need even to start history server.
If it is the first time you start hadoop, you need to format the namenode, otherwise the dfs service would not start.